# looping through json data on client side

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method in my controller that returns a json string to the browser. I am attempting to read out the values from the json but have no luck. The first step is to create a simple alert, that will show the First Name. Can someone please take a look. Thanks.

Json the Controller Generates:

```
"[{\"FirstName\":\"Mic\",\"LastName\":\"Muffin\"},{\"FirstName\":\"Eddie\",\"LastName\":\"Munchie\"},{\"FirstName\":\"Hollowin\",\"LastName\":\"Wolf\"}]"
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetNames() {
    List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
    p.Add(new Person()
    {
        FirstName = "Mic",
        LastName = "Muffin"
    });
    p.Add(new Person() { 
        FirstName = "Eddie",
        LastName = "Munchie"
    });
    p.Add(new Person() { 
        FirstName = "Hollowin",
        LastName = "Wolf"
    });
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string n = jss.Serialize(p);
    return Json(n, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Client Side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("/Home/GetNames", {}, function (data) {
            var x = data;
            $.each(x).alert(x.FirstName);
        }, "json");
       //$.post("/Home/GetNames", { }, function (data) {
       //   alert(data);
       //}, "json");
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: if you are wrapping everything inside `[]` in quotes at server get rid of the external quotes otherwise it's invalid json. When in doubt paste full response into jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't need to serialize to JSON in your controller, that is why you are getting a string in your JavaScript and jQuery can't automatically parse the response into an object. So just fix your action and everything will be cool:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetNames() {
    List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
    p.Add(new Person()
    {
        FirstName = "Mic",
        LastName = "Muffin"
    });
    p.Add(new Person() { 
        FirstName = "Eddie",
        LastName = "Munchie"
    });
    p.Add(new Person() { 
        FirstName = "Hollowin",
        LastName = "Wolf"
    });

    return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Anyway, to deserialize string into an object in JavaScript you should use `JSON.parse` method:

```
var x = JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is because of json serialization in controller, that's why jQuery can't deserialize the result into object

Comment: right, just noticing the extra quotes... would be smarter to fix at server and return valid json

Comment: @charlietfl I've posted a server-side fix too

Comment: @Vsevolod, when I debug in chrome and enter in the loop, it crashes when it goes to parse the JSON? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After running it through debug a few times, I noticed where I was going wrong. The controller did its job fine. But on the client side, I needed to go a bit farther to get the data I needed. So this code worked out for me.

```
    $.post("/Home/GetNames", {}, function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(data[i].FirstName);
        }
```

Comment: Can be just `$.each(data, function(index, item) { console.log($(this).FirstName); });`